# Sequelize: Query same join table with different conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two models `Contact` and `Thread` with a many to many relationship represented across a join table `ThreadContacts`.

I need to write a query to **find a Thread which has associations with an exact list of Contacts**. For example, I might have a list of `contact_id`'s 
[1,2,3,4], and I need to find a `Thread` that is associated with these exact 4 contacts.

I have tried including `Contact` on a findAll query:

```
Thread.findOne({
    include: [{
        model: Contact,
        where: { id: $in: [1, 2, 3, 4] },
    }],
})
```

Of course this doesn't work because it'll return a thread that has a ThreadContact with any of the 4 ids.

I need something like this:

```
Thread.findAll({
    include: contactIds.map(id => ({
        model: Contact,
        where: { id },
    }),
})
```

However this also doesn't work because it is including duplicates of the same model.

What are my options here? I'm having a difficult time finding a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing more complicated join queries in sequelize, I usually end up using the [raw query interface](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#querysql-options-promise). It looks a bit complicated, but hopefully it makes sense:

- Select the Threads and join with the ThreadContact table
- Group by `Thread.id`
- Aggregate the group using [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) on the contact ids. So we now have an array of all associated contacts for each thread.
- Then filter to where the aggregated array 'contains' (as represented by `@>`) your inputted filter. See [postgres array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html).

The result will be all Threads which are associated with at least those 4 contacts.

```
sequelize.query(`
  SELECT Thread.*
  FROM Thread
  INNER JOIN ThreadContact
    ON Thread.id = ThreadContact.threadId
  GROUP BY Thread.id
  HAVING array_agg(ThreadContact.contactId) @> ARRAY[:contactIds];
`, {
  model: Thread,
  mapToModel: true,
  type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
  replacements: {contactIds: [1, 2, 3, 4]},
});
```

Also note that the column names may be incorrect from how your model is defined, I just made some assumptions on how they would look.

Comment: Useful as alternative, also this is what I use when I need to do `joins`, however still would like to see example of "sequelize" way of doing this.

Comment: Yeah, would be nice to see it in Sequelize...but this works perfectly for my application. Thanks :)

Comment: Just one thing I had to add, because the array needs to contain the *exact* list of contact ids: `HAVING array_agg(thread_contacts.contact_id) @> ARRAY[:contactIds] AND
        array_agg(thread_contacts.contact_id) <@ ARRAY[:contactIds];`

Comment: Great solution! Just note that you don't have to use an entirely raw query for this to work. This could instead be written as: `Thread.findAll({ include: { model: ThreadContact, required: true }, group: ['Thread.id'], having: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('array_agg', 'ThreadContact.contactId'), '@>', contactIds) })`, or something along those lines. Generally, limiting how raw your queries are can help in terms of security and maintainability.